# REITERATE BETWEEN DATE RANGE AND FIND EACH OF THE DATES

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to make a userform that can be used by staff to book holiday in advance to minimize overlapping holiday request.

Basically now I am planning to generate a list of dates from entered start date and end date, then looping around the array, search for the dates one by one.

Here is what I manage to scrap together but when I debug the error would be "For without Next"
 - so I tried to put "Next i" at line 71 but then the error come out as "Next without for block" :(

2)I would like to lock have All Calendar Sheets (JAN-DEC) . Read something about locking and unlock using vba but nothing happened in my trial :(

I really appreciate any points to learn and help.

Thank You very much

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim strdate, enddate, rngedate As Date
Dim rCell As Range
Dim IReply As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim d As Date
Dim x As Integer
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

strdate = Me.tbDtF.Value
enddate = Me.tbDtT.Value
If strdate = "False" Then Exit Sub  'Cancelled
strdate = Format(strdate, "Short Date")
On Error Resume Next
If enddate - strdate <> 0 Then 'generate list of date base on entry to buffer worksheet
ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Buffer")
With ws
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).endxlup.Row
End With
ws.Range("A1").Value = strdate
ws.Range("B1").Value = enddate
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")

ColIndex = 0
For i = strdate To enddate
OutRng.Offset(ColIndex, 0) = i
ColIndex = ColIndex + 1
Next

'looping all date to find
For i = 1 To lastrow
rngedate = Range("A" & i).Value
 ' If ws.Name = "LIST" Then Exit Sub  'to look for date in calendar sheets only
Set rCell = Worksheets(UCase(Format(strdate, "mmm"))).Cells.Find(What:=CDate(rngedate), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1  'adding value 1 to the cell below found date
rCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = rCell.Offset(2, 0).Value + " " + Me.tbUser.Value 'adding the username to the cell

If rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value < 6 Then  'limit for ppl on leave per day is 5
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LIST") 'sending userform entry into worksheet "list"
i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Cells(i, 1).Value = Me.tbUser.Value
.Cells(i, 2).Value = Me.tbDtF.Value
.Cells(i, 3).Value = Me.tbDtT.Value
.Cells(i, 5).Value = Me.tbRemarks.Value
End With

MsgBox "Your leave booking is submitted"
Else: MsgBox "Sorry, maximum people have applied for leave on" & rCell & "that date"
End If


End If
If enddate - strdate = 0 Then
Set rCell = Worksheets(UCase(Format(strdate, "mmm"))).Cells.Find(What:=CDate(rngedate), After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
'MsgBox "Found at " & rngX.Address
If rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value < 6 Then  'limit for ppl on leave per day is 5
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LIST") 'sending userform entry into worksheet "list"
i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Cells(i, 1).Value = Me.tbUser.Value
.Cells(i, 2).Value = Me.tbDtF.Value
.Cells(i, 3).Value = Me.tbDtT.Value
.Cells(i, 5).Value = Me.tbRemarks.Value
End With
rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value + 1  'adding value 1 to the cell below found date
rCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = rCell.Offset(2, 0).Value + " " + Me.tbUser.Value 'adding the username to the cell
MsgBox "Your leave booking is submitted"
Else: MsgBox "Sorry, maximum people have applied for leave on" & rCell & "that date"
End If
End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0
If rCell Is Nothing Then
lReply = MsgBox("Date cannot be found. Try Again", vbYesNo)
If lReply = vbYes Then UserForm1.tbDtF.SetFocus
If lReply = vbNo Then UserForm1.Hide
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When posting long blocks of code please **use indenting**.  it's easier for us and for you to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you suggestion is that you use the Database for this, as users can apply on different date for a particular period.

This will give you more options of Previous records, Edit the holiday planner, etc...

If you are using the data base then you can play with the data and put conditions in much more easier way

VBA + MS access will do the trick